# plpgsql passing argument in an if statement

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a synatx issue with plpgsql. What I want to do is use my arguments as a condition for an if statement. I want to combine to processes into one procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name(arg1 int, arg2 date)
returns text as

$body$

DECLARE

arg1 integer;
arg2 date;

Begin
--where I am having the issue

IF EXISTS (%,'%', arg1, arg2)
  THEN
     INSERT INTO some_table.table
END IF;

RETURN 'complete';
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Where I know I am having an issue

```
 IF EXISTS (%,'%', arg1, arg2)
  THEN
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this, or rather, get this to work correctly?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"

Comment: you're missing a BEGIN in your code

Comment: What do you want to do by `IF EXISTS (%,'%', arg1, arg2)` ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, Yes I just saw that, of course, I did in a hurry I will make that correction.

Comment: @Houari, If those arguments are present, do this insert.

Comment: @user3199223 You want to check if your table contains record with `arg1` and `arg2` ?

Comment: @user3199223, No, not my table my actual argument from my sql function. Meaning, `select * from fn_name (args)`. If they exists, proceed within the function call, begin insert.

Comment: @user3199223 Of course they exists, they are in body of your function, and the function is called with its arguments. Perhaps that you want to check those variable if they are `null` or not!

Comment: @user3199223, good idea, let me give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have to check those arguments if they are `null` by:

```
IF arg1 is not null and  arg2 is not null THEN
     --INSERT instruction
END IF;
```

Comment: this will definitely do the trick. I am still getting my bearings with the native language. Thanks!